# Polymorphism in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, polymorphism, abstract-class

Here's my wish to create something abstract in WPF. You've got a main window (called main for example, even if it's not correct we don't care) with two buttons. Those two buttons have the same function : they open a new window, the same for both of them, but with different things inside. So I decided to create an abstract class to rule them like that :

```
public abstract (partial ?) class A : Window
{
    public A()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // Not sure about that, it's kinda weird to use it here no ?
    }

    ...
}

public partial class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // Since it's already in A I shouldn't have to use it here right ?
    }

    ...
}

public partial class C : A
{
    public C()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // Same thing here...
    }

    ...
}
```

Debugging gives me something like : "error CS0263: Partial declarations of 'namespace.B' must not specify different base classes".

Removing 'partial' from A class gives : "error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'namespace.A'; another partial declaration of this type exists".

I know that 'partial' specifies if a class has another part of her somewhere else (like the xaml file beside the cs one), so I guess the abstract class has to be partial too since it contains my controls. Maybe the B class shouldn't be partial ?

I know (memories) it works with Windows Forms, but there's no xaml files so it's easier, and I didn't find any useful tips. I think I understood that this problem occurs when I don't change something in my xaml file, which doesn't works as simply as "class : abstract class". Maybe the subclass thing ?

Please note that I'm a beginner in WPF apps, so I thank you in advance if your answer is as detailed as possible.

Thanks !

Comment: In your xaml files `B.xaml` and `C.xaml` instead of having `<Window ...` you need to use `A` to derive from it for that partial side. So something like `<local:A xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Yournamespace-for-class-A-goes-here-"...` now you can have your `B.xaml.cs` have `public partial class B : A` as both sides derive from A.

Comment: You '*Partial declarations of 'namespace.B' must not specify different base classes*' error is telling you that the other part of your partial class is set to inherit from a different base class... nothing to do with your C# classes.

Comment: @Viv http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957231 -> deriving a XAML generated class from another XAML generated class is not supported.

Comment: @franssu ofc, The OP's class decl for `A` isn't partial. So couldn't have been having a xaml side. Maybe that wasn't clear but yh you are deriving from a code generated class.

Comment: @Sheridan Ok so I was right, thanks, it's where my problem should be then.

I just don't get it correctly for the moment...

Comment: @Adrana, whenever you get a Microsoft `CSxxxx` error, just pop it into a search engine to see what comes up: [Compiler Error CS0263](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2w478hh(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Off side: Much easier with MVVM and inheriting ViewModels.

Comment: @Sheridan Yup I already did it but it's not always as clear as here. Above all when it's your first app. I'll have a look on MVVM and other things too, WPF seems to be very interesting but weird...

Comment: @Adrana, I would agree that WPF is very *different* to other programming languages... while that makes things awkward to understand initially, it is also what makes WPF better than the older UI based languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your base class all in code without using XAML :

Code for class A :

```
public abstract class A : Window { }
```

Code for class B :

```
public partial class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

xaml for class B :

```
<yourNamespace:A x:Class="yourNamespace.B"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:yourNamespace="clr-namespace:yourNamespace"...
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your code sample, but... What do you mean by "all in code without using XAML" ? I mean I added a basic class to my project and it can't use "public abstract class A : Window" since "Window" is highlighted as an error (missing assembly or something).

I don't think the solution is to delete the whole XAML code / file, it sounds crazy.

Answer (score 1):

A C# partial class is one that is defined over two or more source files. The other 'part' of Window is generated by Visual Studio, and includes things like InitializeComponent()

If you want a base Window class, then it has to be defined entirely in code, and have no XAML component. It will then no longer be a partial class.

```
public abstract class WindowA : Window
{
    // define base methods here
}
```

Then you can derive WindowB from WindowA:

```
public partial class WindowB : WindowA
{
    public WindowB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

But you also need to do it in the other 'part', i.e. in XAML, so in WindowB's XAML file, the root Window tag needs to be changed to:

```
<wpfApp:WindowA x:Class="WpfApp.WindowB"
        wpfApp:WindowA ="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
```

(you'll need to change the namespace appropriately)

This will generate the other 'part' deriving from WindowA, so there will be no inconsistency.

The InitializeComponent() method should be called in each derived class' constructor, as it's specific to that class, i.e. in this case, the other 'part' is generated from the XAML, and defines an InitializeComponent() with resourceLocator code that specific to WindowB.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But my answer is the same as above for franssu, the word "Window" in the abstract class is not recognized. I'm sure it's something stupid, sorry, but I don't see how it should work for the moment.

Comment: When you create the WindowA, DO NOT create a WindowA.xaml through "Add new Item". Simply create a new class, and derive from Window. Then it won't be partial.

Comment: Ok this is it thank you @Wayne Maurer, I just added the missing using System.Windows; it seems to work now. I'll post something else if it doesn't. Thank you very much all !

Comment: No probs. If you found any of the answers useful, click the up-arrow (above the '0') and mark the best answer as 'correct' ;-)

Comment: I wish I could but I need to get some more reputation to vote up :( I marked the first code sample as the best answer since I used this one but all others answers were very useful !

Comment: Now I've another question : so I can't use any XAML code in my abstract class, am I obliged to (almost) create twice the same window for my two buttons ? I'm only talking about controls inside, nothing else. I thought I could have put them in the abstract class to be used by B and C...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the way it is ... if you really want the two buttons on the base window, you'll have to do it through code. Which is not really that nice, I know. To be honest, creating a base Window to share controls and functionality is not that common. I would suggest creating a UserControl with your two buttons, and then simply use that UserControl on your two windows. Then the buttons are defined once in the UserControl, and the two windows need only one duplicated line each, i.e. instances of the UserControl.

Comment: Hmm... It sounds too late now, I've so many controls in my window, not sure I have the time and the motivation to recreate it entirely :/ Is your UserControl a window like I wanted to do with my abstract class ? Anyway, about 50% of my controls are called by my two windows, so it's not really important. I'm just a bit disappointed that we cannot do that as I thought, it's not so useful...

Comment: A [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) is simply a control that contains other controls, and that can be reused. Anyway, good luck.